# Python - can I use a decorator for this?

Tags: python, function, python-decorators

```
def f(a,b):
    lista = []
    listb = []
    lista.append(a**2)
    listb.append(b**2)
    return lista, listb
```

but I also want to return an array made from the two lists.

so like:

```
def f2(a,b):
    lista = []
    listb = []
    lista.append(a**2)
    listb.append(b**2)
    tr = np.array([np.array(lista), np.array(listb)]).T
    return tr
```

Both functions share the same arguments, but I would not like to pile up both the lists and the array as returned values.

Can I somehow use a decorator no `f` so as to define another function that just takes the argument of it and does another operation?

Comment: How about `f2` calls `f` instead of using the same code?

Comment: But then I have to give <code>f2</code> the same arguments as <code>f</code>. And I may have already written <code>f</code>, and want to leave it unchanged. I just want to add something that performs the last line of <code>f2</code>.

Comment: If you want to have something as "code" you can use backticks (\`) like \`f\` => `f`

Comment: Note that using a decorator, you will "lose" the original function, so instead, why not have a second function `toArray` that turn the result of any function into an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the following decorator:

```
def tr(func):
    def wrapper(a, b):
        lista, listb = func(a, b)
        return np.array([np.array(lista), np.array(listb)]).T
    return wrapper
```

so that `f2` can be defined as simply:

```
@tr
def f2(a, b):
    return f(a, b)
```

Comment: of more simply `f2 = tr(f)`

Comment: I don't think that this is really a case for decorators, since you want both the decorated `f2` and the original `f` function.